# How can I connect directly to a peer using a DSL modem?

Tags: networking, modem, dsl, p2p

I was wondering if it's possible to connect to a friend using a DSL modem. I know that with voice-band modems, you can dial numbers and have a peer's computer answer the call and communicate with yours to send files etc, but this is slow. Is it possible to communicate with a peer's computer, WITHOUT using any ISPs using the DSL interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

No. The DSL modem *must* connect with a [DSLAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Subscriber_Line_Access_Multiplexer) on the other end of the [loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_loop).

Comment: Dammit. How about the possibility to have multiple people dialing into my computer using only one telephone line? IIRC, BBSes used to do that?

Comment: BBSes used to run mainly on [POTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_telephone_service), not DSL.  If you need multiple people connect to your system, setup a relevant server so that people can connect to it @phillid

Comment: Yes, I realise they use the POTS, but is it possible to have multiple callers going to my POTS modem at the same time?

Comment: No. The best you can do is set up a [PRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_Rate_Interface) or [BRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Rate_Interface), then use [hunting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_hunting) to make all the lines look like they're on the same number.

Comment: Hmm.. Did BBS hosts used to hire more than one line or use the above technique?

Comment: Depends on how large the BBS was. Smaller ones used multiple POTS lines, while larger ones could afford a PRI.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm trying to make a free web in my local community where POTS calls are free. I was going to have clients dial a compaitible server and use a program to request pages etc. Any sugesstions on how to make it work?

Comment: You're looking for [pppd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_daemon), in server mode.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. This till wouldn't work multi-user, would it?

Comment: Not with only a single line, no. But that's a POTS limitation.

Comment: I think I might use a Dial on Demand approach. My friends expect free, but they can't expect speed. You can't have your cake and eat it, can you.

Comment: A POTS-to-POTS modem connection is limited to 33.6kbps regardless; you need at least a BRI to get 56k.

Comment: Well, my web is initally going to be text-based, so it's plenty.
32768 / 8 = 4096 bytes per second, so it's plenty for text-based stuff.

Comment: It's actually /10, since there is 1 start bit and 1 stop bit on top of the 8 data bits.

Comment: @phillid: If you have two cakes...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, If we're going to nitpick, it's also 33600 bits/second, not 32768. But unless the POTS line is perfect and you use no compression, you can't count on that either; actual throughput in practice may very well be both lower and higher than the theoretical link throughput. A POTS modem link will be transmit-bound no matter what you do, so if you want to, you can throw a lot of effort on compression without bogging the system down any.